# phalcon Invo Users Validation return recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer)

Tags: validation, docker, phalcon, php-7, recv

In register page;
1- Click event first going my users model and checking validation 
`

```
    $validator = new Validation();

    $validator->add(
        'email',
        new EmailValidator([
        'message' => 'Invalid email given'
    ]));
    $validator->add(
        'email',
        new UniquenessValidator([
        'message' => 'Sorry, The email was registered by another user'
    ]));
    $validator->add(
        'username',
        new UniquenessValidator([
        'message' => 'Sorry, That username is already taken'
    ]));
    // until this point there is no problem but after return side 
    return $this->validate($validator);
}`
```

2- until return;  there is no problem but after return giving me  this error.

3- [error] 7#7: *5 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.176.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /register HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.176.3:9000", host: "phalcon.dev", referrer: "http://phalcon.dev/register"

4- I am using docker 
that is my docker

```
version: '2'
services:
################################################################
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    expose:
      - 3306
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: invo
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test123
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin123
################################################################
  app:
    build: ./docker/php/
    container_name: php
    tty: true
    # ports:
    #   - "6900:6900"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginxlog:/var/log/nginx
      - ./invo:/var/www/html
################################################################    
  web:
    tty: true
    image: linxlad/nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./docker/nginx/selfconf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginxlog:/var/log/nginx
      - ./invo:/var/www/html
    links:
      - app
    depends_on:
      - app
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem may be between FastCGI and Nginx

I'd suggest to:

```
- check your fastcgi_process / server
- check your access-log
- enable debug-log
```

Did you also enable opcache? If so, increase memory_consumption to whatever level your site needs. Disabling opcache may also work.

```
# .../fpm/php.ini
[opcache]
opcache.memory_consumption = 392
```

You should also dig from your php/nginx logs and this may help you to point out the real problem you're facing right now.

Comment: $validator->add(
        'email',
        new UniquenessValidator([
        'message' => 'Sorry, The email was registered by another user'
    ]));
    $validator->add(
        'username',
        new UniquenessValidator([
        'message' => 'Sorry, That username is already taken'
    ]));
when comment out this code it is working. There is a problem abouth UniquenessValidator class.

Comment: i did this in php.ini 
opcache.memory_consumption = 392 
default_socket_timeout = 3600

Comment: we need the logs, show us the php and nginx logs, it will help in order to diagnose the problem ;)